Modify multiple vectors or data frames using loop or list
I am working with a script that imports multiple data frames and before passing them to an function that performs an analysis, it creates a vector for each data frame containing all the column names. The script does a check to make sure all of the column names across all the vectors match, if they do, the analysis goes ahead, if not it aborts. Unfortunately my 25 different data frames don't have matching columns, so my question:
How can I loop over all the vectors, remove the column names that don't match and then do the same for the imported data frames. I have created a simplified example below as well as a some of the solutions I have tried.
## goal
# example vectors:
cols_import_1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f') 
cols_import_2 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'cc', 'f')
cols_import_3 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'bb', 'e', 'f')

# what needs to be produced:
cols_import_1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'f') 
cols_import_2 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'f')
cols_import_3 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'f')

## my approach
# create list of loci to remove from vector
remove_loci_list <- c('aa' 
                      , 'bb'
                      , 'cc'     
                      , 'd'   
                      , 'e'     
)

# create vector list
vector_list <- list(cols_import_1
                    , cols_import_2
                    , cols_import_3)

# option 1:
lapply(vector_list, function(change_vector)) {
  change_vector <- change_vector[!change_vector %in% remove_loci_list]
}

# option 2:
for (i in 1:length(vector_list)) {
  vector_list[[i]] <- vector_list[[i]][!vector_list[[i]] %in% remove_loci_list]
}

# option 3:
for (i in 1:length(paste0('cols_import_', [i]))) {
  cols_import_[i] <- cols_import_[i][!cols_import_[i] %in% remove_loci_list]
}

# option 4:
for (i in 1:length(paste0(cols_import_, [i]))) {
  paste0(cols_import_, [i]) <- 
    paste0(cols_import_, [i])[!paste0(cols_import_, [i]) %in% remove_loci_list]
}

# option 5:
for (i in 1:length(vector_list) {
  cols_import_[i] <- cols_import_[i][!cols_import_[i] %in% remove_loci_list]
}


Note, you have a typo in the lapply.

Apparently you want the intersect of the column names of all datasets. In your simplified example, put the column names in a list,
> (cols_lst <- mget(ls(pattern='cols_import_\\d+')))
$cols_import_1
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "f"

$cols_import_2
[1] "a"  "b"  "c"  "aa" "cc" "f" 

$cols_import_3
[1] "a"  "b"  "c"  "bb" "e"  "f" 

use Reduce to get the intersect in column names, and
> (cols_int <- Reduce(intersect, cols_lst))
[1] "a" "b" "c" "f"

again intersect the individual column names.
> lapply(cols_lst, intersect, cols_int)
$cols_import_1
[1] "a" "b" "c" "f"

$cols_import_2
[1] "a" "b" "c" "f"

$cols_import_3
[1] "a" "b" "c" "f"

Since I assume, your example is oversimplified, you may import your data in a list, which I resemble here,
> (imp_lst <- mget(ls(pattern='^import_\\d+')))
$import_1
   a  b  c  d  f
1 NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA

$import_2
   a  b  c aa cc  f
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA

$import_3
   a  b  c bb  e  f
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA

determine the intersect of the column names,
> (icols_int <- Reduce(intersect, sapply(imp_lst, names)))
[1] "a" "b" "c" "f"

and subset the data frames using the bracket function `[`().
> lapply(imp_lst, `[`, icols_int)
$import_1
   a  b  c  f
1 NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA

$import_2
   a  b  c  f
1 NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA

$import_3
   a  b  c  f
1 NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA


Data:
cols_import_1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f') 
cols_import_2 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'cc', 'f')
cols_import_3 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'bb', 'e', 'f')

import_1 <- as.data.frame(
  array(NA, c(3, 5), dimnames=list(NULL, c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f')))
)
import_2 <- as.data.frame(
  array(NA, c(3, 6), dimnames=list(NULL, c('a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'cc', 'f')))
)
import_3 <- as.data.frame(
  array(NA, c(3, 6), dimnames=list(NULL, c('a', 'b', 'c', 'bb', 'e', 'f')))
)


We can use lapply to apply an anonymous function over vector_list. \(x) ... (introduced in R 4.1.0 from May 2021) is the equivalent of function(x) {...}, and here that function is essentially "take x and only output those elements not in remove_list."
lapply(vector_list, \(x) x[!x %in% remove_list])

result
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "f"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "f"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "f"

